# Reflection: Assembly.GetExportedTypes requires all assemblies to be present

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies

I want to analyze assemblies using reflection.

Specifically, **I want to find out if a certain interface is implemented in a type in the assembly.**

Not all references of the assembly are present on the machine though, which is why I need to analyze them.

So when I call `GetTypes` or `GetExportedTypes`, a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, telling me that a "referenced assembly cannot be loaded".

This is true, but still **I want to know what types are implemented in this assembly**.

Reflector can do it somehow. How can this be done?

EDIT: I just found out about `Mono.Cecil`, does exactly what I want in an easy way. However, it is an external library and no built-in solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCI might be kinda heavyweight for what you want, but it can reflect over assemblies without having them all loaded: http://cciast.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still hoping somebody knows a standard .net way without using external assemblies. Otherwise I might come back to this library.

Comment: CCI and Mono.Cecil is the current "standard" way, as so many commercial or open source projects (NDepend, Sandcastle) are built upon them. Reflection is by far the most unpleasant way, so I don't think it will become the "standard".

Answer (score 2):

I need to do the same thing, and after hours of searching, I came across [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1425057&page=34).

The code you need is at the bottom of the thread.  It doesn't get you all the way, but it at least lets you get a list of all the types in an assembly even without having all of the dependencies.

EDIT: Here is the code snippet used in the referred link:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(args.Name), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    _dumbAssemblies.Add(args.Name, ab);

    return ab;
}

private Dictionary<string, AssemblyBuilder> _dumbAssemblies;
```

What it does is create dumb assemblies for each assembly that is missing, so this avoids the `FileNotFoundException` from being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and figured this out:
Using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile()`

It works for me at least! :-)

```
Assembly asm;
Type[] types;

asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\path\assembly.dll");
types = asm.GetTypes() // throws FileNotFoundException.

asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path\assembly.dll");
types = asm.GetTypes() // Works!
```

`Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` behaves the same as above, too.

Comment: How does this provide a solution to the problem in the original question?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really clear. Using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` will allow you to get the assembly's types, even if its references/dependencies are missing.